# Google Sites, insert a pdf reachable with a link

Tags: google-sites

in my website made with Google Sites I would like to insert a link that opens a pdf.
I have the pdf file on my computer: where should I upload it?
(in website it must be hidden, it must only open by clicking the link).

Thank you,
C.